# SQL Server Configuration manager doesn't show the IP

Tags: sql-server

Sorry for stupid question.
I'm trying to set up the remote connection to the SQL Server.
In all tutorials I watched people have their IPs shown in the TCP/IP properties window(under SQL Server Network Configuration-->Protocols for MSSQLSERVER). Please see the picture.
But I have only the port.
Where can I see the IP? What should I do to see it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I guess your issue could be because:

1. ...you are using the default instance (can be read as: Not a Named instance) of SQL Server, which in this case is MSSQLSERVER.
2. ...your computer is probably only configured to have one IP address.

#### First Solution

In this case SQL Server Configuration Manager doesn't have to provide you with  multi-IP configuration options, as you instance will either listen to your computer's IP address or not.

#### Second Solution

Your SQL Server Configuration Manager (SSCM) did not install correctly and the IP settings were not entered into the registry correctly as was pointed out by ant1008 in his answer.

If the registry doesn't contain the IP addresses, then they won't be displayed in SSCM.

The fix for such an issue is to run the **Microsoft SQL Server XXX (64 Bit)** setup program in Windows **Programs and Features**. Then select the **Repair** option and fix the **Shared Components** and the **MSSQLServer** instance. This will require two runs to get it right.

Reboot your server/laptop/pc.

Run SSCM.

#### Third Solution

If you want to see the configuration settings for two IP addresses, then add an additional IP address to your network adapter. The steps are:

1. Open the Network Adapter settings ...
   [image: Properties of Ethernet0]
2. ...and open the Properties
   [image: Properties of internet protocol, version 4 ...]
3. In the Extended TCP/IP settings enter a new IP address via **Add..** (Hinzufügen... in my screenshot)
   [image: Extended TCP/IP settings]
4. Close all Network dialog windows with OK.
5. Reboot your server/laptop/pc
6. Run the Repair steps as outlined in my **Second Consideration**.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

What the version of SQL Server are you using?

Please make sure you open the same version of SQL Server Configuration Manager if you have multiple different version SQL Server instances.

You can use the following query to view the raw data with your network protocols:

```
SELECT registry_key, value_name, value_data 
FROM sys.dm_server_registry
WHERE registry_key LIKE '%SuperSocketNetLib%'
```

See [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5626/determine-sql-server-network-protocol-information-using-tsql-and-dmvs/) for more details.

Regards,

Amelia

Comment: Please see above the result of the query. No ip address.

Answer (score 0):

Listen All specify whether SQL Server will listen on all the IP addresses that are bound to network cards on the computer. Please set the values of it to Yes. Restart the SQL server service to make the change effect. Then restart the SSCM.

Comment: Could you please specify where "Listen ALL" is located? Maybe it's obvious to you, but it's not obvious to me (and the other users who will view this question). Thanks.

Comment: @kostinalex  You get it follow below: SSCM -> SQL server network configuration-> Protocols for MSSQLSERVER->TCP\IP properties ->Protocol tag->Listen All

Comment: It was set to ListenAll-Yes initially. There are no IPs.

Answer (score -2):

Can you go to Registry Editor to see all IPs: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQLXX.[Instance Name]\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib\Tcp\ .

Ensure that the version of SSCM used is the same as that of SQL Server.

There may be several reasons why you cannot see the IP:

1.Related keys in registry is corrupt

2.Components of SQL Server Configuration Manager(SSCM) is corrupt

Comment: as I mentioned on your other answer, don't add irrelevant links.